# iPhone Xr's notch size in pixels

Tags: iphone, size, screen, iphone-x, iphone-xs-max

What is the size (in pixels or points) of the notch of the **iPhone Xr** and the **iPhone Xs Max**? I know them for the iPhone X, see "iPhone X Cutout" on https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-x-screen-demystified
I believe the iPhone Xs has the same dimensions.

I'm trying to make a game that hugs the space right up to the pixel.

Comment: its 30 X 209 Pt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via @prabhat-kasera

> It's 30 X 209 Pt

I see now what my error was: I was using `30/2436 %` of the screen for both phones.

I should use `30/1624` for iPhone Xr and `30/2688` for iPhone Xs Max.

Device-agnostic code:

```
// Landscape
float screenRatio = 30 * ((float)UIScreen.mainScreen.scale) /
    UIScreen.mainScreen.currentMode.size.width;

// Portrait
float screenRatio = 30 * ((float)UIScreen.mainScreen.scale) /
    UIScreen.mainScreen.currentMode.size.height;
```